sscanf: how to parse
I'm trying to parse this string:
+CGDCONT: 0,"IP","free","10.158.88.34"
In bold are the items i'm interested in.
My first attempt was to use this pattern:
"+CGDCONT: %d,\"IP\",\"%*s\",\"%d.%d.%d.%d\""

with it, only 1 variable is parsed.
Then, I tried:
"+CGDCONT: %d,\"IP\",\"free\",\"%d.%d.%d.%d\"  // the string "free" is hard coded

It works but "free" might not be always "free", so I need a way to ignore it.
Then, I tried:
"+CGDCONT: %d,\"IP\",\"%s\",\"%d.%d.%d.%d\"  // the string "free" is no more optionnal

with it, 2 variables are parsed. The second one (%s) is parsed as
free","10.158.88.34"\8  // \8 is ascii char 8.

How should I do?

*scanf() is the wrong tool for this job.

The %s format reads space-delimited strings. Since there's no space it will read everything.

As a workaround, if you really want to use sscanf, perhaps use \"%*[^\"]\". That will read up to but not including the ending ".

If you can rely on the input being regular enough, and / or if you're careful enough about writing a correct format, testing for errors, and validating your results, then you could probably get scanf to work for this.  But it's not well suited.  You should instead be using a regex.  Or, depending on context, maybe writing a mini-language parser.

Will the input string always start with "+CGDCONT: "? Will the item that is "10.158.88.34" in your example always be immediately after the third comma?

If "free" were ever to become, say, "free, but not cheap", I doubt you'd be able to compose a scanf() format specifier that would work...

If you want, effectively, a one-liner you can do it like this:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char inp[] = "+CGDCONT: 0,\"IP\",\"free\",\"10.158.88.34\"";
    int val = -1;
    int arr[4] = { -1, -1, -1, -1 };
    printf("Processing %s\n", inp);

    if(sscanf(inp, " +CGDCONT: %d ,\"IP\", %*[^,], \" %d.%d.%d.%d\"",
            &val, &arr[0], &arr[1], &arr[2], &arr[3]) != 5)
        return 1; // handle error

    printf("val = %d, arr[] = %d %d %d %d\n", val, arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3]);
}

The first substring is matched before the bolded 0 or other int, which is processed (the leading space is to filter previous newlines etc). The next substring is matched, the next is skipped using %*[]. Then the comma and quote are matched, followed by the four dot-separated int values.
Program output:

Processing +CGDCONT: 0,"IP","free","10.158.88.34"
val = 0, arr[] = 10 158 88 34


As already mentioned in a comment by someone else, the function sscanf is not well suited for this task.
Assuming that

the input string always starts with "+CGDCONT: ", and
the IP address is always immediately after the third comma, and nothing else comes afterwards,

then you could

extract the "CGDCONT" value by parsing the input string and moving past "+CGDCONT: ", and then extract everything up to the next comma, and
extract the IP address by finding the third comma and extracting everything that comes afterwards.

Here is an example:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// This function will extract the value after "+CGDCONT: " up to
// the next comma. On success, it will return true, otherwise it
// will return false.
bool extract_CGDCONT_value( const char *input, char *buffer, size_t buffer_size )
{
    static const char prefix[] = "+CGDCONT: ";
    static const size_t prefix_length = sizeof prefix - 1;
    const char *p;
    size_t num_bytes_to_copy;

    // return false if input input string does not start
    // with "+CGDCONT: "
    if ( strncmp( input, prefix, prefix_length ) != 0 )
        return false;

    // make "input" point immediately after "+CGDCONT: "
    input += prefix_length;

    // find next comma, and return false if not found
    p = strchr( input, ',' );
    if ( p == NULL )
        return false;

    // calculate number of bytes to copy
    num_bytes_to_copy = p - input;

    // return false if output buffer is not large enough to store
    // the result
    if ( num_bytes_to_copy >= buffer_size )
        return false;

    // copy the result to the buffer provided by the caller
    memcpy( buffer, input, num_bytes_to_copy );

    // write terminating null character to buffer
    buffer[num_bytes_to_copy] = '\0';

    // everything went ok, so return true
    return true;
}

// This function will extract everything after the third comma.
// On success, it will return true, otherwise false.
bool extract_IP_address( const char *input, char *buffer, size_t buffer_size )
{
    size_t num_bytes_to_copy;

    // attempt to find the third comma
    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        // attempt to find the next comma, and return false if
        // it does not exist
        input = strchr( input, ',' );
        if ( input == NULL )
            return false;

        // make "input" point one character past the comma
        input++;
    }

    // calculate number of bytes to copy
    num_bytes_to_copy = strlen( input );

    // return false if output buffer is not large enough to store
    // the result
    if ( num_bytes_to_copy >= buffer_size )
        return false;

    // copy the result to the buffer provided by the caller
    strcpy( buffer, input );

    // everything went ok, so return true
    return true;
}

int main( void )
{
    const char input[] = "+CGDCONT: 0,\"IP\",\"free\",\"10.158.88.34\"";

    char CGDCONT_value[200];
    char IP_address[200];

    if ( extract_CGDCONT_value( input, CGDCONT_value, sizeof CGDCONT_value ) )
    {
        printf( "Extracted CGDCONT value: %s\n", CGDCONT_value );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "Failed to extract CGDCONT value.\n" );
    }

    if ( extract_IP_address( input, IP_address, sizeof IP_address ) )
    {
        printf( "Extracted IP address: %s\n", IP_address );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "Failed to extract IP address.\n" );
    }
}

This program has the input from the question hard-coded into it, and for that input, it gives the following output:
Extracted CGDCONT value: 0
Extracted IP address: "10.158.88.34"


@Fe2O3: The function strrchr must first go from the start to the end of the string before it can start looking for the last comma, whereas if you look for the third comma from the start, you must traverse a smaller amount of the string. On the other hand, strchr must compare every character with two values when traversing the string, whereas strrchr must compare every character with only one value, so strrchr probably moves at a faster speed. Also, strrchr would only have to be called once instead of three times, so function overhead would be less of an issue.

@Fe2O3: One thing that my function extract_IP_address does is to verify that there actually are three commas. Otherwise, the function returns false. If I used strrchr instead of strchr, then I would not be able to perform this input validation. Therefore, I think I prefer using strchr. However, you are correct that using strrchr would make the code simpler if input validation were not desired.

@Fe2O3: Yes, my input validation is incomplete. However, since OP did not provide much information about the format, I did not want to make too many assumptions about the format. If we assume that OP's input is in CSV format, and it is possible that a field contains a comma, then I would have to add a test for each comma whether it is in quotation marks or not.

CSV? There's probably 1 or 67 SO Q&A examples addressing that... Cheers! :-)
